# Python,ConfigParser-Referencing in earlier directory

Tags: python, configparser

In my downloads folder, I have a folder called bin. Within the folder bin I have a file called config_template.ini, and another folder called SN. Within the folder SN I have a file called sample.py. In sample.py I use:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config_template.ini')
```

Since 'config_template.ini' is not in the same folder, how would I reference it?

This is the file address of sample.py:

```
C:\Users\user1\Downloads\bin\SN\sample.py
```

This is the file address of the config_template file.

```
C:\Users\user1\Downloads\bin\config_template.ini
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the absolute path:

```
config.read(r'C:\Users\user1\Downloads\bin\config_template.ini')
```

Note the `r` in front of the string, so the `\` does not need to be escaped.

Or more fancy, go up one path from where your python file is:

```
import os
inifile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'config_template.ini'))
config.read(inifile )
```